# Deprecated: Hook block_editor_settings is deprecated since version 5.8.0! Use block_editor_settings_all instead

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

Deprecated: Hook block_editor_settings is deprecated since version 5.8.0! Use block_editor_settings_all instead. in wp-includes/functions.php on line 5754
I am getting this error while using the default WordPress editor in the backend. I am using the latest version of WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that one of your plugins or your themes is using the block_editor_settings hook which is no longer supported; you'll have to use the [block_editor_settings_all hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/block_editor_settings_all/). If this is an issue after deactivating all plugins and using a default theme like twentytwenty, [contact WordPress support](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/block_editor_settings-is-deprecated-since-version-5-8-0/) for a possible bug.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your reply. Let me check themes and plugin confliction.